# header menu to sidebar toggle not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, sidebar

I'm tryng to make a responsive header menu . The main idea is that an sidebar will substitute the navigation bar links with the width of the screen and an icon with an onclick function to toggle that sidebar will appear at the header. I made de HTML and CSS, but can't make the JS function to add a class to the navigation menu (to show it) work. BTW i'm a begginer developer, started a month ago and still struggling a lot (the code also has a lot of placeholders and temporary CSS properties

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div id="container">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <a href="/" id="nav-brand">Placeholder.</a>
        <ul id="nav-menu">
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#about-me">01. Sobre mim</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#experience">02. Experiência</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#projects">03. Projetos</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#contact-me">04. Contato</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><button id="resume-btn">Currículo</button></li></div>
        </ul>  
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <h3 onclick="handleMenuToggle()">&#9776</h3>
        </div>         
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="introduction">
      <div>
        <h2>
          Hi, my name is
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>
          Placeholder
        </h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="about-me">
      <h2>01. About me</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="experience">
      <h2>02. Experience</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">
      <h2>03. Projects</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact-me">
      <h2>04. Contact me</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(10,25,48,255);
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#container {
  width: 1800px;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

@media(max-width:1800px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#nav {
  margin: auto 30px;
}
 
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 8px #3e3e3e99;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
  }

  .show-nav {
    right: 0;
  }

  #nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

#link {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

#link:hover {
  color: gray;
}

#resume-btn {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(10,25,48,255);
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s, border-color 0.15s;
}

#resume-btn:hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: aqua;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function handleMenuToggle() {
  const navContainer = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
  navContainer.classList.toggle('show-nav')
}
```

Can't make Js onclick function work to toggle sidebar.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/qBymPgx?editors=1111 Please have a look at this if it's what you're looking for

Comment: The idea was that the header menu should appear if the screen width is bigger than 900px. If it's less than 900px, the menu would be hidden and the icon that has the onclick function would appear. The function would show the header menu, but now as a sidebar, to fit the smaller screen

Comment: You don't need js at all to create a responsive menu. You're already using `@media` queries and you can use them to hide/show things based on the width of your choosing so different items appear or are hidden based on the screen width. You can even keep the js, still the layout can be changed through `@media` queries.

Comment: But can I create some type of toggle button using @media queries? I know i could make a menu appear/disappear with the width of the screen, but i wanted to make something like this (change the width of the window): https://brittanychiang.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close to getting this to work.  You just need to change one line in your CSS to make it work (see the working demo below):

```css
/* add #nav-menu to this declaration */
  #nav-menu.show-nav { 
    right: 0;
  }
```

The issue is CSS specificity.  Because you've used an ID to declare the `right` property at `-100%`, even when you add the `show-nav` class to the element, the class alone in the declaration doesn't have enough specificity to override the right property value.

Learn more about [css specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```js
function handleMenuToggle() {
  const navContainer = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
  navContainer.classList.toggle('show-nav')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(10,25,48,255);
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#container {
  width: 1800px;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

@media(max-width:1800px) {
  #container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#nav {
  margin: auto 30px;
}
 
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 8px #3e3e3e99;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
  }

  #nav-menu.show-nav {
    right: 0;
  }

  #nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

#link {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

#link:hover {
  color: gray;
}

#resume-btn {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(10,25,48,255);
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s, border-color 0.15s;
}

#resume-btn:hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div id="container">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <a href="/" id="nav-brand">Placeholder.</a>
        <ul id="nav-menu">
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#about-me">01. Sobre mim</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#experience">02. Experiência</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#projects">03. Projetos</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><li><a id="link" href="#contact-me">04. Contato</a></li></div>
          <div id="nav"><button id="resume-btn">Currículo</button></li></div>
        </ul>  
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <h3 onclick="handleMenuToggle()">&#9776</h3>
        </div>         
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="introduction">
      <div>
        <h2>
          Hi, my name is
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>
          Placeholder
        </h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="about-me">
      <h2>01. About me</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="experience">
      <h2>02. Experience</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">
      <h2>03. Projects</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact-me">
      <h2>04. Contact me</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit neque vitae sint illo, excepturi totam quia atque deserunt aut quasi modi molestias dignissimos quibusdam quidem nostrum eligendi, saepe voluptas. Omnis?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm gonna give a better look at this property